# Fastest way to download file on site using java

Tags: java, url

I am writing a Java code to download large amount of zip files on site using http protocol, and each file is around 1MB(1024KB) size.

I know there are a lot of ways to doing that. I am just wandering which is the fastest, and I would like to know the progress of each downloading like showing a percentage number or something.

I am just giving my version of code , any ideas on how to improve it?

Thanks All.

```
 public static void downloadFile(String downloadUrl , String fileName) throws Exception {
    URL url=new URL(downloadUrl); 
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    int filesize = connection.getContentLength(); 
    float totalDataRead=0; 
    java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fileName); 
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);
    byte[] data = new byte[1024]; 
    int i=0; 
    while((i=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0) { 
        totalDataRead=totalDataRead+i; 
        bout.write(data,0,i); 
        float Percent=(totalDataRead*100)/filesize;
        System.out.println((int)Percent);
    }    
    bout.close(); 
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Ask this type of question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unless you have a dedicated 1 Gb link to the internet, how you do it in a code really won't matter much. i.e. the bottleneck is not your code. The main improvement you can make is to make sure you are using all your bandwidth, by using more than your fair share of their bandwidth.  I would consider using a buffer of at least 1.5 KB as this is the packet size. e.g. try 2 KB

Answer (score 5):

You are optimizing prematurely. The network bandwidth bottleneck is likely going to far outweigh any processing you are doing.

You don't need to wrap the InputStream in a BufferedInputStream. You *may* want to favor larger read buffer sizes, but that may have minimal effect depending on the underlying implementation of the InputStream returned by the connection, kernel level buffering, etc.

For a progress bar, take what you've read so far and divide it by connection.getContentLength(), but note that getContentLength() may return -1 if the length is unknown (it simply gives you the value of the Content-length header). As you're reading the data, pass the progress info along to whatever you choose to do to display it to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer . I totally agree with you on that the bandwidth is the main bottleneck. so Is there any open source library can do better than write it by yourself , maybe I can use it.

Comment: @xuqin1019 You can use Apache commons IO and it will save you a few lines of code (but add a library)

Answer (score -4):

I don't know, mine took 8 hours. To reduce it from 24 hours I cancelled all other downloads, didn't use the internet, and killed all other background tasks.